# Selenium Test Suite: Failover test execution

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, testng

I have a test suite written up in Java using Selenium-RC and TestNG, per -

```
public class testSuite extends SelenestTestCase {

@BeforeTest 
... 
@Test
...
@Test
...
@AfterTest
...
```

To improve robustness, I need to implement a set of steps that would be executed in case any of the commands within a `@Test` fails. These steps could simply be the restoration of the initial test state, so the next `@Test` can be executed.

Any ideas on how this can be implemented within this framework?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own [test listener](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-listeners) and annotate your test class. Or just use @BeforeMethod and set the initial state before each test.

Comment: The @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod annotations worked like a charm. Thanks! I will explore the test listeners too.